# Why does the Humility/Opalescence interaction work?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

There's a ruling on [Opalescence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOpalescence%5d) that explains the interaction with [Humility](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHumility%5d) (as mentioned [in this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/28055/how-do-opalescence-and-humility-interact)).

However, I'd like an explanation of why this is the case. I get that, due to the layers, the type-setting applies first.

However, ability-adding/removing applies before power/toughness. Why do Humility and Opalescence both set power and toughness *after* Humility has removed the abilities from both cards?

Is it that, once you start applying *some* of a single ability, you apply the entire ability, even if that application happens across multiple layers? If this were so, the interaction only occurs because Opalescence "gets in early" by setting type, which means that it will still finish being applied after Humility removes its ability?

Comment: Note that Humility does _not_ remove Opalescence's ability because Opalescence is not a creature (it turns all _other_ non-Aura enchantments into creatures). However, Humility does remove it's _own_ ability...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct on both points.

- The entire ability will be applied in the appropriate layer, as mentioned in the first part of [Opalescence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOpalescence%5d)'s gatherer ruling :

> [...] the type-changing effect applies at layer 4, but the rest happens in the applicable layers. The rest of it will apply even if the permanent loses its ability before it's finished applying. [...]

- [Opalescence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOpalescence%5d)'s type-setting ability works because it's applied in an earlier layer (layer 4) than [Humility](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHumility%5d)'s abilities-removing (layer 6).

Edit : Also works because [Opalescence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOpalescence%5d)'s doesn't affect itself, as Benjamin Cosman mentioned.

Comment: Ah! So if there were two Opalescences they'd lose their abilities but the end result would be the same?

Comment: @Samthere Adding more Opalescences into the mix actually produces different effects depending on timestamps order.
[Here's a very detailed article by Chris Walton, including at the end an explanation of what happened with several Opalescences.](http://www.gatheringmagic.com/lesson-humility/)